# google chrome tearing with integrated intel graphics, but working with optirun

Tags: nvidia, google-chrome, lightdm, bumblebee

Whenever I run google-chrome, I get a lot of tearing issues. These are easy to notice, for example, when scrolling on facebook. The top bar, the one with the logo and the notifications button, tears during scrolling.

However, if I run chrome with optirun there are no issues at all. I could just use chrome like this, but I'm really curious as to why this is happening.

What logs / info should I attach?

```
    lspci | grep VGA
    00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller (rev 09)

    lspci | grep NVIDIA
    01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK107M [GeForce GT 740M] (rev a1)

    uname -a
    Linux k56 3.13.0-46-generic #77-Ubuntu SMP Mon Mar 2 18:23:39 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I've also had some issues with lightdm. It sometimes freezes and does not respond to "service lightdm restart".

edit:

more info:

```
dpkg -l | grep mesa
ii  libegl1-mesa:amd64                                    10.1.3-0ubuntu0.3                                   amd64        free implementation of the EGL API -- runtime
ii  libegl1-mesa-drivers:amd64                            10.1.3-0ubuntu0.3                                   amd64        free implementation of the EGL API -- hardware drivers
ii  libgl1-mesa-dev                                       10.1.3-0ubuntu0.3                                   amd64        free implementation of the OpenGL API -- GLX development files
ii  libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64                                 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.3                                   amd64        free implementation of the OpenGL API -- DRI modules
ii  libgl1-mesa-dri:i386                                  10.1.3-0ubuntu0.3                                   i386         free implementation of the OpenGL API -- DRI modules
ii  libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64                                 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.3                                   amd64        free implementation of the OpenGL API -- GLX runtime
ii  libgl1-mesa-glx:i386                                  10.1.3-0ubuntu0.3                                   i386         free implementation of the OpenGL API -- GLX runtime
ii  libglapi-mesa:amd64                                   10.1.3-0ubuntu0.3                                   amd64        free implementation of the GL API -- shared library
ii  libglapi-mesa:i386                                    10.1.3-0ubuntu0.3                                   i386         free implementation of the GL API -- shared library
ii  libgles2-mesa:amd64                                   10.1.3-0ubuntu0.3                                   amd64        free implementation of the OpenGL|ES 2.x API -- runtime
ii  libglu1-mesa:amd64                                    9.0.0-2                                             amd64        Mesa OpenGL utility library (GLU)
ii  libglu1-mesa:i386                                     9.0.0-2                                             i386         Mesa OpenGL utility library (GLU)
ii  libglu1-mesa-dev                                      9.0.0-2                                             amd64        Mesa OpenGL utility library -- development files
ii  libopenvg1-mesa:amd64                                 10.1.3-0ubuntu0.3                                   amd64        free implementation of the OpenVG API -- runtime
ii  libosmesa6:amd64                                      10.1.3-0ubuntu0.3                                   amd64        Mesa Off-screen rendering extension
ii  libosmesa6:i386                                       10.1.3-0ubuntu0.3                                   i386         Mesa Off-screen rendering extension
ii  libwayland-egl1-mesa:amd64                            10.1.3-0ubuntu0.3                                   amd64        implementation of the Wayland EGL platform -- runtime
ii  mesa-common-dev                                       10.1.3-0ubuntu0.3                                   amd64        Developer documentation for Mesa
ii  mesa-utils                                            8.1.0-2                                             amd64        Miscellaneous Mesa GL utilities
ii  mesa-utils-extra                                      8.1.0-2                                             amd64        Miscellaneous Mesa utilies (opengles, egl)
```

bumblebee:

```
dpkg -l | grep bumblebee
ii  bumblebee                                             3.2.1-90~trustyppa1                                 amd64        NVIDIA Optimus support
ii  bumblebee-dbg                                         3.2.1-90~trustyppa1                                 amd64        NVIDIA Optimus support - debugging symbols
ii  bumblebee-nvidia                                      3.2.1-90~trustyppa1                                 amd64        NVIDIA Optimus support using the proprietary NVIDIA driver
```

edit 2:

I am also having issues with totem. When running without optirun, I get some tearing at the corner of the video. With optirun, no issues.

Comment: What's the output to `lsb_release --short --codename&&uname --kernel-release` and `apt-get dist-upgrade`?

Comment: `trusty
3.17.0-031700-generic` No dist-upgrade available.

Comment: No dist)upgrade?  What's the output???  And then try: `sudo apt-get upgrade` and provide the output as well...

Comment: `sudo apt-get upgrade 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.`
Same for dist-upgrade

Comment: Found out why I'm running 10.6: I've got the xorg-edgers PPA installed...  Do you know what this is and how to install???

Comment: Yes, I had that PPA before. I had some other issues (with my dual monitor setup) and it seems that some packages from there were the cause of my issues. So I had to remove it.

Comment: What's the output of `nvidia-settings --version`?

Comment: `nvidia-settings:  version 346.47  (buildd@lgw01-26)  Wed Feb 25 16:02:48 UTC
2015`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after having some problems with lightdm as well (probably related) I decided to install gdm. Which seems to have fixed all the other issues as well!